# MongoDB count documents for each array elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I h

```js
{
  code : "X1",
  elements : ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
},
{
  code : "X2",
  elements : ["C", "D"]
},
{
  code : "X3",
  elements : ["A"]
}
...
```

I would like to know the number of documents present for each type of value in the "elements" array.
es.
es.

```
"A" : 2
"B" : 1
"C" : 2
"D" : 2
```

is it possible with a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) your array to get single document per element and then run [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to count elements:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$elements"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$elements",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

EDIT: you can use additional group with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to return your ids as keys and counts as values:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$elements"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$elements",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            counts: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$count" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$counts" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qLFUqsfMaKe)