# Count by elements in list and by field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection that looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "owner" : "Alice", airline: "RSAirlines", "content" : ["shoes", "pants", "sockets"]}
{ "_id" : 2, "owner" : "Bob", airline: "RSAirlines", "content" : ["phone", "pants"]}
{ "_id" : 3, "owner" : "Charlie", airline: "RSAirlines", "content" : ["shoes", "pants", "bag"]}
{ "_id" : 4, "owner" : "Mary" ,airline: "AirES" "content" : ["sandals", "coins", "sockets"]}
{ "_id" : 5, "owner" : "Olivia", airline: "AirES", "content" : ["gloves", "pants", "sockets"]}
{ "_id" : 6, "owner" : "Dan", airline: "AirES", "content" : ["sockets", "wallet"]}
{ "_id" : 7, "owner" : "Erin", airline: "AirES", "content" : ["pants", "sockets", "dress"]}
```

I would like to `aggregate` them to get the following results:

```
{ "_id": "RSAirlines", "counts": {
    "shoes": 2,
    "pants": 3,
    "sockets": 1,
    "phone": 1,
    "bag": 1
}}
{ "_id": "AirES", "counts": {
    "sandals": 1,
    "coins": 1,
    "sockets": 4,
    "wallet": 1,
    "dress": 1,
   "pants": 2
}}
```

Previous I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348823/mongodb-count-documents-for-each-array-elements) for counting the elements, but now I would like to count them by `airline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `content` array
- `$group` by `airline` and `content` and get the total count
- `$group` by the only `airline` and construct `counts` array key-value format
- `$arrayToObject` convert key-value array to object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$content" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        airline: "$airline",
        content: "$content"
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.airline",
      counts: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.content",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { counts: { $arrayToObject: "$counts" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AehxVRG-N8n)

Comment: If I would like the top `n` of each content?

Comment: can you give an example, i am not getting exactly.

Comment: Like for the top 2, it would ouput:
`{ "_id": "RSAirlines", "counts": { "shoes": 2, "pants": 3, }} { "_id": "AirES", "counts": {"sockets": 4, "pants": 2 }}`

Comment: see this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r2xlMJYnD75), you can use $sort by count and $slice to select number of elements.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for, thanks